# How to hook on customizer section expanded/active/opened event?

Tags: theme-customizer

I am trying to run js function when customizer section is expended and cant seem to find any event to do so.

Something like this

```
wp.customize.bind( 'ready', function() {

    wp.customize.section.bind( 'expand', function() {
            console.log('hello');

    }); 

} );
```

or

```
wp.customize.bind( 'ready', function() {

    wp.customize.section.on( 'opened', function() {
            console.log('hello');

    }); 

} );
```

or anything that triggers when section is active/activated/expanded/opened.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Here it is

```
wp.customize.bind( 'ready', function() {

    wp.customize.section.each( function ( section ) { 

        section.expanded.bind( function( isExpanding ) {

            if(isExpanding){

                console.log(section);
            }


        });


    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting particular section, then you can do like:

```
wp.customize.section('title_tagline').expanded.bind(function (isExpanded) {
  if( isExpanded ) {
    // Do something here.
  }
});
```